# Bluetooth PAN role as NAP on Windows

Tags: windows, bluetooth

Bluetooth stacks on windows and their PAN profile support

1. Microsoft stacks - only supports PANU
2. Bluesoleil stack - PANU and GN role. Doesn't support NAP.
3. Toshiba stack - PANU and GN role. Doesn't support NAP.
4. Broadcomm/Widcomm - PANU only. This [link](http://www.blueradios.com/hardware_USB.htm) suggests Microsoft security concerns intentionally restricting for NAP/GN in Vista system.

BlueZ Bluetooth stack on Linux can take NAP role. But on Windows(XP/Vista/Win7/8), is it impossible to take NAP role ? It is acceptable to use any bluetooth sdk.

Comment: Try to install old WIDCOMM Stack. 6x versions doesn't work on Windows XP. I used 5.0.1.801 version.
Sorry, but I'm lazy to register here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluetooth PAN-NAP works correctly under Windows XP with WIDCOMM/Broadcom Bluetooth Stack. In my practice I couldn't setup NAP under Windows 7 and Vista.
I recommend you setup Windows XP on your PC.

Comment: Downloaded Widcomm 6.1.0.1506 SDK and saw NAP role. Couldn't try with Win XP though. SDK is also no more avaialble for download and had to be downloaded from Softpedia